# Imagemagick how to apply gravity and extent to only short images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, minimagick

I have a web page where I list images that should be 600px by 600px (width & height). So I resize all big images to 600x600 using imagemagick, which works fine.

However, some images, when I resize them (in order to keep their aspect ratio), get resized to a size smaller than 600px in height (for example 600x450). So I tried to fill the needed height by using imagemagick options (gravity, background, and extent) like so :

```
image.combine_options do |img|
    img.crop('1200x1200+0+0')
    img.resize '600x600'
    img.background 'white'
    img.extent '600x600'
    img.gravity 'center'
end
```

That gave me what I want for these kind of images (short images). However, this effect of **centering** is applied to the other images (bigger ones) as well ! Is there any way to prevent that ?

**Update:**

Just to show you what I mean, I made up this example... if I don't add extent and gravity the image will start from the top left corner

[image]

but if I add extent and gravity (center) the image will start from the center, something like this :

[image]

I want only images that result on resized images smaller than 600x600 to be centered, but in the example as you see even an image that get resized to exact 600x600 get centered !! that's not what I want

**the solution :**

I end up using shell command using **system** function in ruby

```
system "convert #{image.path} -crop 1024x1024+0+0 -resize 600x600 -background white -gravity center -extent 600x600 output.png"
```

and that worked fine! I don't know why minimagick wasn't working correctly, but I just get rid of that gem from my gemfile which is fine too.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the actual `imagemagick` shell command, that's generated by this dsl construct.

Comment: @FaZeUnempl0yedd it should soemthing like this : `convert image -crop 1200x1200+0+0 -resize 600x600 -background white -gravity center -extent 600x600 result`  also I updated my question to show and example-like of what I get

Comment: I would suggest you resize your input images to 1024x1024 first, then crop and add +repage. The repage is need for PNG image, but not for JPG to remove the virtual canvas. The resize will optimize the space your image occupies. For smaller images, this will prevent too much padding. For larger images, it will avoid center cropping.

Comment: @fmw42 your suggestion of resizing to 1024x1024 didn't work for me, it makes the image skinny and centered with a white padding ( right and left sides) .... but the essential is that the simple command has worked so I prefer to use the shell command :) I accepted your question below, thank you again! much appreciated your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your command in command line Imagemagick with proper resetting of the virtual canvas after the crop.

```
convert image -crop 1200x1200+0+0 +repage -resize 600x600 -background white -gravity center -extent 600x600 result
```

Here are two results with slightly different resize arguments. It looks like your commands are using the equivalent of the ^ flag set on the resize argument.

**Input:**

[image]

**Proper result without the ^ flag: (Note padded with white)**

```
convert wiki.png -crop 1200x1200+0+0 +repage -resize 600x600 -background white -gravity center -extent 600x600 result1.png
```

[image]

**Result with the ^ flag: (Note cropped)**

```
convert wiki.png -crop 1200x1200+0+0 +repage -resize 600x600^ -background white -gravity center -extent 600x600 result2.png
```

[image]

The above is Unix syntax. For Windows double the ^ to ^^, since ^ is an escape character in Windows.

Perhaps your issue is with minimagick and not Imagemagick. You can check by testing my command line.

Comment: I added repage after crop but not working, also I have +0+0 offsets on the crop (sorry I just forgot to write it in my question), I edited my question to show you an example of what I mean... hope it's clear now

Comment: Post the input so I can test with it. What if you use -gravity northwest or no gravity?

Comment: what do you mean by the input? the image ?

Comment: Yes, but I will post from my input that is similar to yours shortly.

Comment: if I get rid of -gravity the big images doesn't get centered and that's what I want, but if a smaller image the white space (extent) will be added to the bottom and the image don't get centered, I want the small images to get centered and the white space/color to be added to the top and bottom

Comment: See my addition in my original answer with my new examples. Your resize seems to be resizing with the ^ flag even though you have not asked for it explictly. Have you set some other argument to make it do that? Perhaps some limitation of minimagick? See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry. What version of Imagemagick are you using and on what platform?

Comment: thank you so much for helping me with this.. I find out that the library (minimagick) I was using somehow is the issue, or maybe I did something wrong in my code writing... anyway I ended up using a shell command (no need to repage option at all), see my update in my question. can you just edit your answer and delete the unnecessary parts

Comment: I think minimagick needs IM 6 and either you are trying to use IM 7 or GraphicsMagick. Perhaps that is the issue.